# PhoneGap app works only after first start

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im doing an app for Android. I'm using Genymotion for debug. Everythings working perfectly there.
However, when i'm trying on my phone, the first run after install will go fine. After that i kill the app from the task manager and start the app again. Many of the JavaScripts are failing, some of working, but the weirdest thing is that even `alert()` not working anywhere.
Anybody had the same problem before? Or any advices? Maybe it's a cache, phone, ROM related thing?

UPDATE

What i've tried so far:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>

android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable the [console](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md) plugin of phonegap and watch logcat logs for anything wrong that might have happened.

Comment: My phone has a custom ROM and USB debugging not working with it. Btw, it is installed, but it's a good point, an upvote is deserved.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined at https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js:8179 in Genymotion

Comment: Downloaded a logcat viwer: I exception firing pause event from native at null:1

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any real fix in hours. Tried the unaligned version of the APK and it's working fine, so it must be something with the ziptool, i'll try with other ones.